# Sending/receiving .wav file from Android app to Django server using JSON

Tags: android, python, json, django, audio

I am trying to send a .wav file from my Android app to a Django server. The main problem is that on the server side constantly get this error: **wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id**

From the Client point of view, this is the way I convert the **test_audio.wav** file to **byte[]**

```
HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<>();

InputStream inStream = testPronunciationView.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test_audio);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);

int read;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
    out.write(buff, 0, read);
}
out.flush();
byte[] fileAudioByte = out.toByteArray();

// two options to transform in a string
// 1st option
String decoded = new String(fileAudioByte, "UTF-8");
// 2nd option
String decoded = toJSON(fileAudioByte);

// decoded = either one of above
postDataParams.put("Audio", decoded)

// ....
// prepare a POST request here to send to the server

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

**EDIT:** Method to create the JSON string:

```
public static String toJSON(Object object) throws JSONException, IllegalAccessException
{
    String str = "";
    Class c = object.getClass();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String name = field.getName();
        String value = String.valueOf(field.get(object));
        jsonObject.put(name, value);
    }
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

On the server side I do:

```
audiofile_string = data['FileAudio']

audiofile_byte = list(bytearray(audiofile_string, 'utf8'))
temp_audiofile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.wav')
with open(temp_audiofile.name, 'wb') as output:
     output.write(''.join(str(v) for v in audiofile_byte))

# The following line throws the error
f = wave.open(temp_audiofile.name, 'r') # wave.py library
```

So I think that I am doing something wrong in the conversion or in the post call. Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: I wrote up an answer but deleted it because I hadn't looked at your code closely enough.  It doesn't look like you are even using JSON, but JSON cannot handle raw binary data like that.  IF you were using JSON, one option would be to base64 encode the binary data before putting it into your JSON.

Comment: @mittmemo you are right. I added the method I use to transform an Object to a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are trying to do this using JSON?  You can't just stuff binary data into a JSON string.

If you can avoid using JSON, then just POST the binary data over HTTP using a multipart/form-data request.

If for some reason you are stuck on using JSON, you can use base64 encoding to achieve this.  In your Android app, you need to base64 encode the binary data.  This will result in a string.  You can then send this string in your JSON to the server.  On the server side, you will then need to get this base64 encoded string from the JSON, base64 decode, and then save it to file (or whatever you want to do with the binary data).  Here's some small examples.

client side:

```
int read;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
    out.write(buff, 0, read);
}
out.flush();
byte[] fileAudioByte = out.toByteArray();

String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(fileAudioByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

`encodedString` is a `String` that you will then add to your JSON to send to the server.

server side:

```
import base64
...
audiofile_string = data['FileAudio']
audiofile_byte= base64.b64decode(audiofile_string)
# audiofile_byte now contains the bytes of the audio file, proceed to write to disk
```

Comment: **base64.b64decode(..)** was the key! Thank you very much

Comment: @spaghettifunk hello sir, i m working on the same task. I need help in how to receive encoded .wav file on django server then decode into wav file back. Which field to use and how to use serializer in this case? Any help will be highly appreciated.